# Maximum recursion depth reached faster when using functools.lru_cache

Tags: python, recursion, memoization, python-3.3

I've been playing around with memoization and recursion in python 3.3

Ignoring the fact that python is the wrong language to be doing this in, I've found that I get inconsistent results between **using** `functools.lru_cache` to memoize, and **not using** `functools.lru_cache`

I'm not changing the recursion limit - it stays at the default, which for me is 1000.

To test the problem, I've written up a simple recursive function to sum numbers from 1 through i

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def sumtil(i):
"""Recursive function to sum all numbers from 1 through i"""

    # Base case, the sum of all numbers from 1 through 1 is 1... 
    if i == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return i+sumtil(i-1)

# This will not throw an exception
sumtil(998)

# This will throw an exception
sumtil(999)
```

Running this function normally, I can run `sumtil(998)` comfortably without hitting the recursion limit. `sumtil(999)` or above will throw an exception.

However, if I try decorating this function with `@functools.lru_cache()`, the recursion limit exception is thrown *3 times earlier*, when running `sumtil(333)`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import functools 

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def sumtil(i):
    """Recursive function to sum all numbers from 1 through i"""

    # Base case, the sum of all numbers from 1 through 1 is 1... 
    if i == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return i+sumtil(i-1)

# This will not throw an exception
sumtil(332)

# This will throw an exception
sumtil(333)
```

Being that 332*3 = 996, but 333*3 = 999, it appears to me that the lru_cache decorator is causing each level of recursion in my function to become three levels of recursion.

**Why do I get three times as many levels of recursion when using `functools.lru_cache` to memoize a function?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a decorator is an extra function, so it "uses" one level in the stack. Example:

```
>>> def foo(f):
...   def bar(i):
...     if i == 1:
...       raise Exception()
...     return f(i)
...   return bar
...
>>> @foo
... def sumtil(i):
...     if i == 1:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return i+sumtil(i-1)
...
>>> sumtil(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in sumtil
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in sumtil
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in bar
Exception
>>>
```

Besides, if the decorator uses [argument packing/unpacking](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments), then an extra level is used (though I'm not knowledgeable enough about the Python runtime to explain why that happens).

```
def foo(f):
  def bar(*args,**kwargs):
    return f(*args,**kwargs)
  return bar
```

Max. recursion depth exceeded:

- undecorated: `1000`
- w/o packing: `500`
- with packing: `334`